# SQL If Else Logic

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a staging table with the following structure

```
ID | BookID |Title | Cost |
----------------------------
1  | Test   |1234  | 1234 |
```

This is populated through my system when an excel file is picked up, and I place all of the values inside this sheet into my staging table

I also have another table, for this example I'll call my Specials tables. It has an identical structure to my staging table.

```
ID | BookID |Title  | Cost |
----------------------------
1  | Test   |Mr Men | 4,99 |
```

What I'm doing now is amending a proc that is doing a whole host of calculations based on the data inside my staging table. A typical call to this looks like this:

```
BookTitle = dbo.StagingTable.Title
```

My amendment needs to check to see if in the books name in my staging table is also in the specials table. If it is, then I should bring back that data instead of the data inside of my staging table.

The BookId values are the same in both and I'm doing an `Left Outer Join` to tie them both together. What I'm struggling with is figuring out the correct syntax to do what I want.

```
LEFT OUT JOIN dbo.Specials s on dbo.StagingTable.BookId = s.BookId
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

The above is just small snippets from a larger proc that I can't share. So if things seem odd, that's why. I've simply taken the bits I could to help better explain my issue.

Comment: An inner join will give you all the matches between the 2 tables. Insert it to a temp table an do whatever logic you need.

Comment: @B001 i thought they were one and the same. Plus it was an auto suggestion

Comment: If you can't share the SP, replicate the scenario with example tables, data, queries, etc.  Even consider replicating the example scenario in SQLFiddle or some other environment.  It also helps you isolate exactly which aspect of your query you're looking for help on.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.StagingTable 
WHERE StagingTable.Title 
IN (SELECT Specials.Title FROM dbo.Specials)
```

to get all the rows in the `StagingTable` that have a `Title` that is also present in the `Specials` table.

Comment: Well it will work but if first or second table is big it will work very long.
You should use join instead.

Comment: @VoonArt great point. For each row of StagingTable we are checking if it has the same title as **ANY** row of Specials. But can you explain me why is it better to do a join? After all, a join will be the cartesian product of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Please test following SELECT statement

I hope that is what you require

```
select
staging.ID,
staging.BookID,
Title = case when staging.Title <> isnull(Specials.Title,staging.Title) then Specials.Title else staging.Title end,
staging.Cost
from staging
left outer join Specials on staging.BookID = Specials.BookID
```